# not getting any result by meta field in custom form

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a search form where my form action is this:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/searched-result')); ?>" method="post">
```

On the searched-result template I have this query,

```
<?php
// Only check these form fields (change the list as needed...)
$fields = array( 'custom_price', 'custom_beds', 'custom_garage');
foreach( $fields as $field ) {
    if( $_REQUEST[$field] != '' ) {
        // We have something to match, otherwise ignore the field...
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => $field,
            'value' => $_REQUEST[$field],  // This is OK, WP_Query will sanitize input!
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    }
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property_post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'meta_key' => 'SORTFIELD', // The name of the metakey to orderby
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

?>

<h1 class="title">

<?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Your issue still not solved?

Comment: yesss........ am I doing right thing to show search result on template page ???

Comment: Yes, Glad to hear that your issue is solved :)

Comment: no..... I mean my issue is not resolved.... :(

Comment: can I make a search filter for multiple meta value.... @ Bindiya Patoliya

Comment: so why my code is not working.....

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it will only return results if all meta_values match the criteria. You must add an extra argument called relation, and set it as 'OR': Example:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'color',
        'value' => 'blue',
        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested :

```
$fields = array( 'custom_price', 'custom_beds', 'custom_garage');
foreach( $fields as $field ) {
if( isset($_REQUEST[$field]) && !empty($_REQUEST[$field]) ) {
       // We have something to match, otherwise ignore the field...
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => $field,
            'value' => $_REQUEST[$field],  // This is OK, WP_Query will sanitize input!
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
               );
           }
}
```

Check if your getting value in $_REQUEST.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property_post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'meta_key' => 'SORTFIELD', // The name of the metakey to orderby
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',     
        $meta_query
    )
);
```

Comment: I think i am getting empty $_REQUEST[$field],